# Android use outlook credentials stored in my app

Tags: java, android, outlook

How to use credentials stored on my android device?

Hi! i need to send email with outlook credentials, how can i do for obtain stored credentials?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot obtain credentials stored by any other application in android. That would be a security issue if they allow you to do so. Any malicious application can grab your credentials that way.
Applications can provide data such as saved contacts using [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).